# Lightswitch HTML - screen over-stretches

Tags: css, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have noticed this for a while however that when using Lightswitch and setting properties to "Stretch to Container", that the screen sometimes appears to be over-stretched and moves items down to the next line, for example:

[image]

[image]

When pressing the "See My Projects Only" the buttons switch (so I hide this one and display the other option" using the below code:

if (screen.ChangeDefaultValue.count > 0) {
        screen.ChangeDefaultValue.selectedItem = screen.ChangeDefaultValue.data[0];

```
    screen.ChangeDefaultValue.selectedItem.HomepageProjectsDefault = false;

    screen.DefaultOption = null;

    myapp.applyChanges();

    setTimeout(function () {
        screen.Projects.refresh();
    }, 100);

    screen.findContentItem("SeeAllProjects").isVisible = false;
    screen.findContentItem("SeeMyProjectsOnly").isVisible = true;
}
else {

}
```

This works perfectly, however as you can see in the 2nd image above, the button moves down below the parameter search box as if it has been overstretched. I have tried changing the margin and padding of the .msls-content however this error still occurs here and on multiple of my other pages.

**Has anyone found a fix to this problem?**

Further information:

- I am using msls-2.5.3.css and is declared in the default.htm file
- I have tried this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb1305c5-ac13-474e-8ae0-df74ebf12590/html-client-custom-control-stretch-to-container-sizing-bug-problem?forum=lightswitch

**THE PROBLEM**

this small block of code in the msls-2.5.3.css appears to be the issue however if I comment it out then other screens break. all of the padding in the height appears to disappear and they all overlap each other on the modal screens

```
.msls-clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LightSwitch HTML, we can use column layout option to render the control in each column. By setting "stretch to container" property, column is only stretched to container size and not the control inside each column is stretched with container. Controls are properly rendered inside the container. Issue occurs due to the column width stretches when hide and show the content item and this is not related with component used in the page. Follow the below workaround solution while remove the content item dynamically by click on the button. Please remove the class ‘msls-clear’ on button click or apply clear: none to the class ‘msls-clear’.
`this.element.parents(".msls-column").next(".msls-clear").removeClass("msls-clear")`

Hope this will helps you..!

Thanks,
Francis

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert in CSS but this appears to have fixed my issues:

```
.msls-clear {
    clear: right;
    max-width: 1850px;
}
```

all of the machines I have tested have a resolution of 1920 x 1080 so by reducing the width down slightly it will never over stretch the items.

I did originally comment out the `clear: right;` which worked in internet explorer, however I tested some Syncfusion controls in google chrome/firefox. I could not click on any of them and therefore had to add in the max-width.

If someone can propose a better solution I would be grateful but at least for now this works